# Youtube embed has wrong start time <iframe><javascript>

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

My youtube iframe embed seems to always start at 1490 seconds instead of where it should.

Here are the relevant code sections. Can anyone see where I done goofed?

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

var minsec = m * 60;
var start = minsec+ s;

document.getElementById("ytplayer").src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ video+ "?fs=1"+ "&start="+ start+ "&disablekb=1&controls=0&hd=1&listType=playlist&list=PLsdN-H3xTIDtzeXvWNnf0fh-XqQpVCHhd;autoplay=1";
```

Comment: What are the values of m and s?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on my project by changing the IFrame domain to [www.youtube-nocookie.com](http://www.youtube-nocookie.com) instead of [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?fs=1&start=START_TIME&end=END_TIME" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Change the VIDEO_ID with your video ID, START_TIME with your desired start time, and END_TIME with the end time or in my case same with the start time.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I left this open, it turns out there's some dodginess in chrome where it tries to resume from the last position it was playing from. This was throwing off my testing.